# Can a capacitor be used as a dipole antenna?

Tags: antenna, capacitance

Can a parallel plate/cylindrical/spherical capacitor be used as a dipole antenna?  Isn't a dipole antenna like a capacitor with a small capacitance?

Comment: um, no, it's not like a capacitor with a small capacitance. I must admit I'm not able to follow your analogy here. The idea of the capacitor is that all the energy is stored in the electrical field between the electrodes, whereas the idea of both the theoretical Hertzian Dipole as well as real dipoles is that the energy radiates.

Comment: If you use air or vacuum as a dielectric, maybe. Otherwise the dielectric mismatch will prevent it from working.

Comment: There's no B field, hence no electromagnetic wave.

Comment: You could probably construct a device that exhibits some properties associated with both, but in doing so it would inherently be far from an ideal of either.

Comment: But that wouldn’t be a capacitor

Comment: The concept for a capacitor is high E field between the plates whereas an antenna it must be outside the plate or dipole or patch antenna.

Comment: Well my question is what is the difference between a capacitor and a dipole antenna.  Why is all the energy stored between a capacitor's plates but not between the two conductors of a dipole antenna?

Comment: Then change the question and consider the wavelength of the energy. It is not stored in the antenna.

Comment: @Chu doesn't charging and discharging a capacitor produce electromagnetic waves?

Comment: inside it does.  Energy is stored in the dielectic which is air for antenna . It is not stored in conductors.

Comment: Take two plates connected to your circuit by magical extending wires.  Put the plates close together and you have a "capacitor" start to move them apart and you have a dipole with capacitance hats.  But of course there is no sharp dividing line (although there is some definite periodicity to some aspects of behavior as a function of distance as a fraction of wavelength)

Comment: The difference is that a capacitor dielector is shielded inside and an dipole radiates

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 you left out two "mostly"'s

Comment: Oh, well that does make sense.

Comment: @Tom it produces EM waves at the conductors leading to the capacitor, but not at the capacitor itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The search-term you want is: "patch antenna."

Yes, parallel-plate capacitors are dipole antennas (especially true at self-resonance, usually up in GHz.)  If the plates are smaller than quarter-wave (or the gap is smaller,) then an impedance matching network would be used to boost the volts for electrically-small dipole-mode.

But self-shielding capacitors such as wrapped cylinders won't make good antennas.  They're not symmetrical, and one plate isn't exposed to the outside world.  They're still dipole antennas, but mostly because of their connecting leads, and they're shorted out by relatively gigantic capacitance.

A very recent innovation in iphone antennas from Fractus Inc. is a tiny 2mm cube with metal faces, plus a series inductor for resonance.  It's intended for upwards of 5GHz, see "ground-plane booster:"

http://www.microwavejournal.com/articles/29138-antenna-less-wireless-a-marriage-between-antenna-and-microwave-engineering?v=preview

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=5723706 (PDF)

Answer (score 1):

"Can a parallel plate/cylindrical/spherical capacitor be used as a dipole antenna? Isn't a dipole antenna like a capacitor with a small capacitance?"

No, a dipole antenna is a coil and an inductor in parallel.  The wire is the inductor and the tips of the wire are the capacitor.  A parallel resonant circuit.